# search and replace with sed taking astronomical time for a 38 MB file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a file where I want to replace only lines which has an ending of "at line ;" with "at line [line_number];"

Every even numbered line has the target statement.

example input file:

```
0000001:use test;
0000002:system echo at line ;
0000003:insert into pet values ('9999', '7777');
0000004:system echo at line ;
0000005:insert into pet values ('9999', '7777');
0000006:system echo at line ;
```

example output file:

```
0000001:use test;
0000002:system echo at line 2;
0000003:insert into pet values ('9999', '7777');
0000004:system echo at line 4;
0000005:insert into pet values ('9999', '7777');
0000006:system echo at line 6;
```

I have written a script using awk to generate sed commands. When run, it is taking days to complete the task for a file of 1000055 lines.

Is there a better (scripting based) technique ?

Here is the gist of the current method:

```
$head -6 c.txt
0000001:use test;
0000002:system echo at line ;
0000003:insert into pet values ('9999', '7777');
0000004:system echo at line ;
0000005:insert into pet values ('9999', '7777');
0000006:system echo at line ;

$wc c.txt
 1000055  5500241 39501572 c.txt

$cat c.txt | grep "at line" | awk -F":" '{printf("sed -i \x27%ds/at line ;/at line %d;/\x27 c.txt\n", $1, $1)}' > a.sh

$time sh ./a.sh
```

note: The machine where the test is being run is single vm on a server class machine. I want to post details of it with bench marking tools' results to prove it is not the issue. But I thought it is not required as the problem is obvious (running sed repeated over entire file for 1000055/2 number of times) to somebody who has some knowledge in this context. Btw, I know some people do not like to use cat. But I got used to it. Request to ignore for the sake of main discussion.

Comment: `grep` is not needed here, you can use `awk` for the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 awk '{gsub(/at line ;/,"at line " NR";")}1' sample
0000001:use test;
0000002:system echo at line 2;
0000003:insert into pet values ('9999', '7777');
0000004:system echo at line 4;
0000005:insert into pet values ('9999', '7777');
0000006:system echo at line 6;
```

This will take action on the lines which only ends with `at line ;` and the `awk`'s `gsub` will replace the text "at line" with the real line number using `NR`.

Comment: Why do you match before the code block for at line when it must exist for the gsub to do anything anyway. Also they want to keep the whole `at line`

Comment: This awk based solution is better in terms of performance figures.

    ?time awk '{gsub(/at line ;/,"at line " NR";")}1' c.txt > d.txt
    
    real    0m1.741s
    user    0m0.703s
    sys     0m1.033s
    
    
    ?time sed 's/\([1-9][0-9]*\)\(:system echo at line \)/\1\2\1/g' < c.txt > d.txt
    
    real    0m5.425s
    user    0m4.103s
    sys     0m1.310s

Answer (score 1):

A simple `sed` line should suffice, if the number is the same as in the beginning:

```
sed 's/\([1-9][0-9]*\)\(:system echo at line \)/\1\2\1/g' < file.txt
```